# Are the product, quotient, and composition property of two continuous function hold for two functions with respect to different variables?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For continuous function in single variable case,
we have following:

if  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous function, then:
$$h(x)=f(x)⋅g(y)\; is\; also\; a\; continuous\; function.$$

$$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\; is\; also\; a\; continuous\; function.$$

$$h(x)=(g\circ f)(x)\; is \;also\; a\; continuous\; function.$$

now if we consider two continuous function $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are both mapping from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, but with respect to two different variables. Then, if I defined a new function such that $$h(x,y) =f(x)\cdot g(y)$$ (the dot at here just represent the multiplication case for a example), now the function $h(x,y)$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then, would the $h(x,y)$ still become a continuous function immediately?

Comment: If all is defined (be careful with quotient and composition), then yes, all these operations preserve the continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The projections $\pi_1,\pi_2:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$ are continuous. Thus, $f\circ \pi_1$ and $g\circ \pi_2$ are continuous (as compositions of continuous maps). Thus $$h(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y),$$ expressed as $h = (f\circ \pi_1)\cdot (g\circ \pi_2)$ is continuous, as it is the product of continuous functions.